# htaccess rewriterules for multiple pages with parameters

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite, symbolic-link

In main page index.php I have two href (like menu) for objective.php and news.php
For both objectives and news I sent variables like:

```
<a href="objectives.php?menu=corporate-objectives">  
<a href="news.php?article=meetings">
```

The idea is to load content for each page separately and to change the url's to symbolic links like:

```
/MyTest_proj/corporate-objectives  
/MyTest_proj/meetings
```

I've tried in many ways to rewrite rules in htaccess especially to rewriterule for both pages but most of time work only for the first rewriterule for example:

```
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$ objectives.php?menu=$1  
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$ news.php?article=$1
```

which obviously both page match the same paterns and the meetings was loaded in objectives.php otherwise (or in other case) I got the 401 error...
The question is how do I must put and to write these rewriterules and conditions if there is any **to work for both pages** ?

Comment: I've managed to put the write rules (I think) and it worked, here is the code:
    "RewriteRule ^home(.*)$ index.php"
    "RewriteRule ^news/([-a-zA]+)/?$ news.php?article=$1"  
    "RewriteRule ^objectives/([-a-zA-Z]+)/?$ objectives.php?menu=$1"
I suppose it wasn't work before because I've used the same patterns Also I've changed the href's to display simbolic url's in address bar  
    "<a href="objectives/corporate-objectives">"
    "<a href="news/meeting-news">"        

wich is also worked BUT STILL, I'm not sure if I did the right thing so please I need advice or ok confirmation Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your RewriteRule matches any URL containing alphanumerical strings, thus matching both "corporate-objectives" and "news". Since mod_rewrite will apply the first matching rule, it never makes it to the second.

In other words, you need to make your RewriteRules more specific. Here's an example that should get you started:

```
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]*objectives)?$ objectives.php?menu=$1  
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$ news.php?article=$1
```

This should mean that any URL containing the word "objectives" will load objectives.php, and anything else will load news.php.

Comment: I've managed to put the write rules (I think) and it worked, here is the code:  
    **RewriteRule ^home(.*)$ index.php** 
    **RewriteRule ^news/([-a-zA]+)/?$ news.php?article=$1**  
    **RewriteRule ^objectives/([-a-zA-Z]+)/?$ objectives.php?menu=$1**  
I suppose it wasn't work before because I've used the same patterns Also I've changed the href's to display simbolic url's in address bar  
**<a href="objectives/corporate-objectives">**  
**<a href="news/meeting-news">** 
wich is also worked BUT STILL, I'm not sure if I did the right thing so please I need advice or ok confirmation Thanks!

Comment: The way to know if you did it right is to try it with a variety of URLs and see if it does what you want it to. Only you can say if it works or not!